# SQL query to remove left and right characters in a field

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a sql field that i need to edit out characters on the left and right.
The table name is: cdr
The field name is: dstchannel
The dstchannel field shows the following data: Local/872@from-internal-6acb,1
I just the need the 872 as output
The field always has the same amount of data, so the 872 will be constaint on its position.
How would I go about writing a sql query for mysql?

If I have another query that I want to include this into, how would I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Will the value you want to retrieve always be three characters long?

Comment: yes, the value will always be three characters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number is always 3 characters in length:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(dstchannel, 7, 3) AS x
FROM cdr
```

If the length of the number is variable, you'll need to look for the '@'. In T-SQL (SQL Server), you can use [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(dstchannel, 7, CHARINDEX('@', dstchannel, 7) - 7) AS x
FROM cdr
```

Comment: now how can I add SELECT SUBSTRING(dstchannel, 7, 3) AS x FROM cdr

Comment: to this query Select cdr.userfield, campaignlist.campaignnumber, campaignlist.campaignname, employeelist.employeeid, employeelist.employeename, cdr.disposition, cdr.calldate, cdr.duration, cdr.uniqueid, cdr.accountcode, x From campaignlist Inner Join cdr On cdr.userfield = campaignlist.campaignnumber Inner Join employeelist On employeelist.employeeid = x Where cdr.disposition = 'ANSWERED' And cdr.dst = 8010

Comment: Just replace the x in your query with SUBSTRING(dstchannel, 7, 3) AS x

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiters are always '/' and '@':

```
select substring(dstchannel, 
  locate('/', dstchannel) + 1, 
  locate('@', dstchannel) - locate('/', dstchannel) - 1);
```